# Компилятор с++ выдает ошибку, но по сути ее там нет

Tags: c++

Занимаюсь программированием недавно, столкнулся с такой проблемой:мне необходимо создать постоянно увеличивающийся массив. Я сделал это таким образом: создаю массив на i элементов, создаю другой, кидаю в него все из этого, затем удаляю первый, создаю новый с тем же именем на 1 элемент больше и кладу в него все из второго, так далее... Но компьютер выдает ошибку, что второго массива еще нет (хотя там в условии i != 1), а изначально i=1, то есть не будет никакой ошибки. Постарался объяснить как можно точнее (вряд ли получилось), прикреплю код: 
int i = 1;

```
while (q<6)
{
    if (i == 1) {
        vector3 *s = new vector3[i + 1];

    }
    vector3 *p = new vector3[i + 1];
    if (i != 1) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
            p[i] = s[i];
        }
        delete[] s;
    }

    cin >> q;
    if (q == 2) {
        t++;
    }
    vector3 *s = new vector3[i + 2];
    for (int j = 1; j < i + 1; j++) {
        s[i] = p[i];
    }
    delete[] p;
    i++;

}
```

Comment: "компьютер выдает ошибку" - текст ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: Все уже сделано как надо в классе `std::vector`.

Comment: Ошибку выдает с2065 (s: необъявленный идентификатор)

Comment: А кстати, вы не хотите `vector` использовать? Или вы хотите просто поучиться?

Answer (score 4):

Вот здесь

```
if (i == 1) 
{
    vector3 *s = new vector3[i + 1];
}
```

переменная `s` объявлена и определена в блоке, и за его пределами все, ее больше нет...

Конечно, можно просто вынести -

```
vector3 *s;

if (i == 1) 
{
    s = new vector3[i + 1];
}
```

Но у вас сама логика программы очень и очень хромает. Ну, например, а если `i` равно 2? Тогда память для `s` не выделена, но вы к нему в следующем `if` все равно обращаетесь к `s` - разыменовывая *что*?...
И это далеко не единственная несуразность в вашем коде.

Comment: Она мне и не нужна на 1 шаге, мне необходимо пользоваться массивом s со второго шага, когда i будет равно 2,3,4 и т.д.

Comment: А со второго шага все, уже ее нет, все заново! По окончании итерации цикла все переменные, *объявленные в теле цикла*, тю-тю...

Comment: То есть, переменные не выходят не только за предел цикла, но и за предел итерации?

Comment: http://mycpp.ru/cpp/book/c08.html

Comment: За предел блока, в котором объявлены.